# While searching for iOS app on google showing more than 1 URL for same app? What does this mean?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunes-app

Basically, I am new to **iOS development** and for some reason, I need **iTunes** `URL` of my live app but while googled for the same getting more than one `URL` for the **same APP** is there any specific reason behind this by observation I think this might be for different *countries*.

- E.g,
  While searching for whats app getting these **two links**:
  First one contains **in** and the Second one contains **us**

  1. https://apps.apple.com/in/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997
  2. https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://apps.apple.com/in/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

> It is for India's app store for WhatsApp

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

> It is for the USA's app store for WhatsApp

**Also, available for other countries too such as China**

https://apps.apple.com/ch/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997

Refer [Internet Country Domains list](https://www.worldstandards.eu/other/tlds/) for other countries

That's it. Nothing serious.